# Bootstrap Typeahead ASP.NET (Webforms) data from WebService

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, web-services, webforms, typeahead

my friends.

Many many times I've found the solution for my for my problems at stackoverflow, but for the first time ever, I can' find any here or any place else.

I'm trying to create an ASP.NET (Webforms) app with a themeforest's bootstrap template.

Now, for this app, I need to add an autocomplete textbox that gets the data from the database.

Firstly, I've tryed to add the autocompleteextender using webmethod to get the data. For some weird reason, while typing in the textbox, the event didn't fired up and so didn't get any data.
Then, still trying to use the autocompleteextender, i've tryed with a webservice, but still it didn't fired up.

(In both cases, I've used the bootstrap template. But if I create a blank web page with the autocompleteextender, the webmethod and the webservice works perfectly.) - So I thought that the problem was from the template.

Now I'm trying to create a autocomplete textbox with typeahead, but I can't find any full sample using Webforms. I only can find for MVC.

Can anyone, please, give me some sample how to create a autocomplete textbox with bootstrap and webmethod (or webservice) for ASP.NET Web Forms (not MVC!)?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Ajax is old technology. I think its high time to use jQuery instead of it. See following link for different kind of autocomplete with jquery.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/78704/Different-Approaches-for-Implementing-the-JQuery

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but since I'm working with Bootstrap, I'm looking for samples to use typeahead with asp.net web services...

Comment: You can always use web service with jquery. See the link I have provided it will work with web service also.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've found exactly what I was looking for.
For those who wants to use ASP.NET Forms with autocomplete Typeahead Bootstrap and Web Services, this link has everything you may need: [Creating a simple autocomplete control with Bootstrap for with a remote JSON service](http://toreaurstad.blogspot.pt/2013/07/creating-simple-autocomplete-control.html)